# How to create navbar with Bootstrap 4 where only certain parts are collapsed and certain parts still appear in small and medium screen?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

### THE PROBLEM

By putting `data-target` and `id` to the specific `div` element does work but while expanding the toggle button
 in a medium and small screen, the rest of seen part in the navbar also comes down along with the hamburger button.

### Tired

I put the `navbar-toggler` at the end of all the `nav-link` but still while expanding the `navbar-toggler` the rest of the seen part and hamburger button comes down.

#### Expected Output

`navbar-toggler` should expand but the rest of the seen part and hamburger button must be at the top with the navigation bar.

**Code is down below**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DASA</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Men <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Women</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kids</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
```

[Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/p/1zyXHlCnhi) code is here.
Thank you.

Comment: I was just unknown about it, from now onwards I will be using the bootstrap 4.5.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap 4 `order` classes to order the mobile menu last...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand order-0" href="#">DASA</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right order-lg-0 order-last" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Men <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Women</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kids</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" 
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
</nav>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/CvIXtKJda9)

Comment: I understood whatever comes just before the hamburger, it expands that. And `order class` took the `div` element at last in a medium and small screen.